# Apply ng-class based on length of Input

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a input box where I can count characters. This input box is called ng-model="social.text". I can get that thing's length by going social.text.length.

Now, I want to subtract input.text.length from 280, so I have {{280-social.text.length}}

All this works without a hitch.

However! In the counter that I want to set up, I want to change its background color to yellow, if the math returns something under 100, and to red if it goes below 50.

So I have css classes set up that apply a background-color.

Now, I need to somehow apply these classes based on the length of the string.

```
<div class="chip" id="socialCounter">
    {{280-social.text.length}}
</div>
```

So how do I apply ng-class to that? I'm quite lost here, so I'm sorry if I seem a bit incoherent.

Comment: You could work with *ngif / else and make 3 blocks, one from 0 to 50, one from 51 to 100 and one bigger than 100. In ever block you make a fixed class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) To achieve the same

```
<!--css  -->

.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}

<!-- html -->

<div class="chip" id="socialCounter" ng-class="{'yellow':(280- social.text.length) <100 && (280- social.text.length) > 50  ,'red':(280- social.text.length) <50}" >
{{280-social.text.length}}
</div>
```

[plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/nBp6xvgtuQFXd5bsCMfF?p=preview)

Comment: That works perfectly fine, although I did add a .white class just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-class` directive to add separate classes for the `div` according to the two conditions you provided.

```
ng-class="{'yellow' : (280 - social.text.length) < 100 && (280 - social.text.length) > 50, 'red' : (280 - social.text.length) < 50}"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('stackoverflow', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="stackoverflow" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="social.text">
  <div class="chip" id="socialCounter" ng-class="{'yellow' : (280 - social.text.length) < 100 && (280 - social.text.length) > 50, 'red' : (280 - social.text.length) < 50}">
    {{280-social.text.length}}
  </div>
</div>
```